# Eclipse: How to move the .externalToolBuilders directory?

Tags: eclipse, ide, external-tools

I have built a small External Tool Builders for 3 eclipse projects.
How can I tell eclipse to use a (shared) directory outsite of the project directory?

I figgerd out that eclipse stores that settings in the .project file. But it seems that it is not possible to change the value:

```
<buildCommand>
    <name>org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder</name>
    <arguments>
        <dictionary>
            <key>LaunchConfigHandle</key>
            <value>&lt;project&gt;/.externalToolBuilders/do cleanup.launch</value>
        </dictionary>
    </arguments>
</buildCommand>
```

I tied the values:

- `&lt;project&gt;/../MyUtils/ExternalToolBuilders/do cleanup.launch`
- `../MyUtils/ExternalToolBuilders/do cleanup.launch`
- `x:/full/path/to/file/do cleanup.launch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<dictionary>
    <key>LaunchConfigHandle</key>
    <value>&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;launchConfiguration local=&quot;false&quot; path=&quot;/MyUtils/ExternalToolBuilders/docleanup.launch&quot;/&gt;</value>
</dictionary>
```